# Lines commented out in Linux configuration files

Tags: linux, ssh, comments, configuration-files

I'm trying to find out why in Linux service configuration files almost all of the lines are commented out. I cannot find the answer.

What is the valid configuration then? Is it hardcoded somewhere in the system and changes in config files (for example by uncommenting and changing the value) apply by overwriting the default configuration (in commented out lines)?

What is a result of uncommenting of such lines? As far as I know it should do exactly nothing. Then why are they commented out?

I know it may sound a bit silly but I really want to know why such mechanism was implemented, it's a bit unintuitive.

This question applies to lots of services e.g. SSH service after installation.

Comment: Commented lines often are provided by the developer to make it easier for users to configure the product by just uncommenting the specific lines they need.  You can use `grep -v '^#' /etc/ssh/ssh_config | grep .` to quickly view the active lines only.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of it, but my point is: from what location does the system take the information about default values of a service configuration and is there a way to access them by the user? Or is it just hardcoded by the developer who created the service?
I mean, there are some default setting stored 'somewhere'. While restarting the service, parser goes through the content of config file and "reacts" to uncommented lines and then overwrites those defaults with those set in the configuration file. Am I correct?

Comment: The product should (and will in many cases) give information about default values in its documentation.  Often there is a four-step defaulting:  ① Hardcoded, overridable by ② config file, overridable by ③ environment variable, overridable by ④ command line parameter.  So, if you provide a command line parameter, this will take precendence.  Otherwise what's in a specific environment variable or in the config file will be used.  If nothing's found, a hard coded default is used.

Comment: In `man sshd` I find: `command line option: -p port: Specifies the port on which the server listens for connections (default 22). […] Ports specified in the configuration file with the Port option are ignored when a command-line port is specified.`

Comment: Thank you, now it's all clear for me, at least in this case :)

Answer (score 1):

Also, let's have a look at an example taken from apache2.conf:

```
#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5
```

Its structure is different because commented lines contain only explanation to the options that are below.
However, in SSH installed by default, all of the lines are commented out, even including basic settings as the port number used by the service.

Answer (score 0):

there are many reasons to keep commented out entries in the configuration files. e.g. to know what are the possible configurations I can use or to let people know that there's a failsafe if they mess the config up.knowing that there are defaults will save you in case errors are made when updating the configuration file.
e.g. if I decide to update `ListenAddress` and set it to `127.0.0.1`, it might be good to know that I can simply comment that entry out to get back to the standard behavior instead of remembering the specific entry inserted.

In other cases the value that you're seeing is not a default but a suggestion of a possible rule.

e.g. from my sshd_config file

```
# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think you missed a point a little bit, but I'll explain mine more clearly.
Let's have a look at e.g. X11Forwarding. This line is commented out by default.

1. If this line is commented out then system is not aware of it - at least from my point of view. Or is it?

2. If the system is aware of the fact that this is set to "no" despite of the line in sshd_config file being commented out, where is this value stored?

3. What happens when I simply uncomment the line? It shouldn't change anything and X11Forwarding should still be set to "no".

Comment: The line `# X11Forwarding no` documents that this line can be used (without the hash mark) to disable X11 forwarding (which some users might want).  The default probably is ›enabled‹ in such cases.  So as long as this line stays commented-out, the default is active.

Comment: @Alfe
Ok, so what about a line that specifies a port used by SSH? It's '# Port 22' by default, and the default port for SSH is also 22. Where is this value stored if not in this particular config file?

Comment: There's a default built-in in the executable of the ssh daemon, so if the config files doesn't specify an override, 22 is used.  In the provided config file there might be a line `# Port 22` to make clear how to override the default (namely by putting a line like `Port 8022`) but because the provide has no clue what to override the 22 with (as that's totally up to the user and no particular value is general enough to put it in the template config), they just state `# Port 22` again.  The line `Port 22` would not change anything of course.

Comment: "The line Port 22 would not change anything of course."
I think it should change something but only in the background - daemon would probably (just guessing) override (or just compare, depends on what is hardcoded in the executable, I didn't check that) the value in the config file to the hardcoded one. Anyways, the result for the service would be the same and those are just theoretical terms.

However, thank you, it's all clear now :)